# How to "jump" the frame of an arbitrary python generator running instance from pdb/pdbpp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

Suppose you have this generator :

```
def gen():
  for i in range(10):
    yield i-5
```

And then you do that :

```
try :
  for a in gen():
    print(5 / a) # Obviously, it will crash on a=0
except:
  import pdb; pdb.xpm() # I'm using pdbpp actually
```

Once the debugger started (either vanilla pdb or pdbpp), is there a way to "enter" inside the generator (go to its execution frame), to inspect its internal variables, without interrupting the program (I mean, to just "observe" and being able to coninue the execution as if the debugger were never launched) ?

**EDIT**

If it could help, in real code, I still have a reference to the generator, so it "more" like this :

```
g = gen()
try :
  for a in g:
    print(5 / a) # Obviously, it will crash on a=0
except:
  import pdb; pdb.xpm() # I'm using pdbpp actually
```

Comment: Obviously, this code is not useful, it's just to illustrate the kind of situation you could need it. in real life, I'm debugging an app making extensive use of asynchronous stuff, and being able to "go back" where the error origins could be a major speed up in the debugging process

Comment: generally you attach a debugger first so it can keep track of stackframes, exceptions etc. never seen it attached after the fact and doubt it would work as it can not really collect the debugging information anymore?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: There's post-mortem mode, where the debugger inspects the stack trace to show you something kind of like what the program state looked like when the exception occurred.

Comment: @user23 cool, gotta look into that

Answer (score 0):

With code like you originally posted, you can't inspect the generator.

The generator's already gone at the point you launch the debugger. The only reference to the generator was on the value stack of the frame object where the loop over the generator occurred, and that reference gets cleared as the exception propagates. Here's a program demonstrating this fact:

```
class DelPrintIterator:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return 1
    def __del__(self):
        print('Deleting iterator')

try:
    for i in DelPrintIterator():
        1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Too late')
```

This prints

```
Deleting iterator
Too late
```

showing that the iterator becomes unreachable before any code in the `except` block runs.

---

Now, *with* a reference to the generator, something like

```
g = gen()
try:
    for a in gen():
        print(5 / a)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    ...
```

then... well, I don't know of any debuggers that would let you "step into" the generator's stack frame when it's not on the stack, but you can manually retrieve the frame with `g.gi_frame` and then start looking through the same attributes the debugger uses, like `frame.f_locals` or `frame.f_lineno`. (Frame object attributes are listed in the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module docs.) It'll be less convenient than the debugger's interface, but the same information is still there.

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to say I still have a ref to it... (but I think because of the traceback, there is still a ref to it anyway)

Comment: @hl037_: The stack trace doesn't keep a reference - it keeps local variables alive, but not value stack entries.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to dig up how pdbpp can access it post mortem^^. Anyway, I in the code, I have a way to get a reference to the generator